# Difference between "à bord" and "à son bord" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Recently I have heard both of these variants in the news with reference to the missing Argentinian submarine:

> ....avec 44 marins à bord.
>
> ....avec 44 marins à son bord.

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is essentially the same, but  there are sentences where you're forced to used one or the other.

> Tout l'équipage est à bord.

You didn't mention the boat so you can't use "*son*"

> Le sous-marin compte 25 personnes à son bord

You're talking about the submarine's crew, so "*son*" is needed to indicate the genitive case.

Comment: The question was "avec N marins à [son] bord" and in the case of "avec" the "son" is not mandatory. But in your example I agree that it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

the "son" is related to the boat in which the sailors are.
Both forms are correct but the "son" version put a slight emphasis that the boat might be important. For example the boat has been named earlier in the sentence.